# Trying to sum the prices of every instance of an item

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a column with item descriptions, a column with the prices for each individual price, a column for the item quantities, and a column with the Price x Quantity.

What I want to do is find every instance of the item and total it's Price x Quantity into a single cell. I'm sure there's an easy way to do it but I'm just drawing a blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are people down voting my question? I'm sorry that i'm new to this site. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data as shown:

[image]

the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5="apple")*(D1:D5))
```

yields 52

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have a question though, what does the "--" do in the formula?

Comment: Why not SUMIF? `=SUMIF(A:A,"apple",D:D)`

Comment: The double minus is used to convert an array of **TRUE/FALSE** into an array of **0/1**.

Comment: ....but as you have * here the -- isn't required. The formula will get the same result without --

Comment: @barryhoudini:   the problem is my shabby mind......can't always remember if the criteria range goes first or the summed range goes first!.......you are also correct about not needing the **--** in this case.

Comment: The more you know! This worked pretty fantastic, I'll need to do a bit of tweaking to get it the way I want but I've learned a very valuable formula. Thanks everyone!